# @PrepareForTest of TestNG annotation not supporting the Spring autowiring?

Tags: spring, testng, powermockito

I am working with **TestNG, PowerMockito and Spring.**

Spring is injecting beans with Mockito with the **Mockito.initMocks(this) annotation** but when I use the PowerMockito to mock the static method of Singleton class, I added Singleton class to the **@PrepareForTest("singletonclass name")** the spring autowiring is not working.

I found some of the solutions with Junit, PowerMockito and Spring but my requirement is **TestNG, PowerMockito and Spring**.

I am getting **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext** exception